# Languages made in C#

Tags: c#, programming-languages

Does anybody know of any languages written in C# that I can play around with and learn from?

Thank you

P.S. I have searched for them but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: What do you want to learn? and why does it matter if a language was written in C#?

Comment: I want to learn how to build just a simple language in C#. I'm most familiar with C#, and I'm the type who learns by "doing", so...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would check out [IronRuby](http://ironruby.codeplex.com/), [IronPython](http://www.codeplex.com/IronPython) ... As far as i know these are mostly written in C#...

**Edit:** I wasn't sure about this so I went and checked. [Boo](http://svn.boo.codehaus.org/browse/boo/trunk/src/Boo.Lang) is also written mostly in c# it seems.

Comment: @jwwishart - You're a genius! I downloaded Boo late last year, and I'd completely forgot all about it. I didn't even know at the time what it was written in! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

[Boo](http://boo.codehaus.org/Boo+Primer) is written in C#

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth taking a look the [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) parser generator.  There's a .NET version, and it can be used to build your own language interpreter or compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The [Mono CSharp compiler](http://www.mono-project.com/CSharp_Compiler) itself is also written in C#.

Comment: Thank you heaps @mythz. I am checking it out now :)

Answer (score -1):

I think there are no such languages available.